# Windows server 2003 check disk fails

Tags: windows-server-2003, ntfs

I tried doing ntbackup and got a lot of errors saying there were corrupt files and eventually it would come to one that it could not deal with and abort.  This is what I get when running chkdsk:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator>chkdsk c:
The type of the file system is NTFS.

WARNING!  F parameter not specified.
Running CHKDSK in read-only mode.

CHKDSK is verifying files (stage 1 of 3)...
725312 file records processed.
File verification completed.
2802 large file records processed.
0 bad file records processed.
0 EA records processed.
2 reparse records processed.
CHKDSK is verifying indexes (stage 2 of 3)...
10 percent complete. (18661 of 1888792 index entries processed)
File record segment 1960 is unreadable.
10 percent complete. (19199 of 1888792 index entries processed)
File record segment 1970 is unreadable.
File record segment 1971 is unreadable.
File record segment 1972 is unreadable.
11 percent complete. (35906 of 1888792 index entries processed)
Correcting error in index $I30 for file 6803.
Correcting error in index $I30 for file 6803.
Correcting error in index $I30 for file 6817.
Correcting error in index $I30 for file 6817.
16 percent complete. (173647 of 1888792 index entries processed)
File record segment 45733 is unreadable.
File record segment 45734 is unreadable.
File record segment 45735 is unreadable.
File record segment 45736 is unreadable.
File record segment 45737 is unreadable.
File record segment 45740 is unreadable.
File record segment 45741 is unreadable.
File record segment 45743 is unreadable.
File record segment 45746 is unreadable.
22 percent complete. (340222 of 1888792 index entries processed)
File record segment 129101 is unreadable.
37 percent complete. (772265 of 1888792 index entries processed)
An unspecified error occurred.
```

I already ran it with the repair option and it aborts using that as well.

A tech came in and replaced the drives.  He was able to get a disk image and move it.

It only moved the problems to a new disk.  We cannot restore from a backup because we recently build this system and do not have a backup and would like to avoid starting from scratch.

Also, I tried easy backup ultimate and that did not work either.

Another thing, I created a folder and created 7000 random files in it after the new drives were put in.  When trying to back it up, ntbackup did not fail, but did give me numerous corrupt file errors.  I would think if it was the drives, creating new files and backing them up would not give me errors unless the file system was trashed and somehow caused them to be wrong.  the files that it says are corrupt, I can open with an editor and save them.  They still come up as corrupt on the backup.  If I copy the files, the copies are corrupt as well.

Pretty weird.

I am looking for suggestions on the best way to proceed and how to trouble shoot the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you recently built this system and don't have backups, starting from scratch is exactly what you want to do.  Your filesystem seems to be suffering from massive corruption.  Even if chkdsk fixes it there maybe strange unexplainable errors later on from damaged OS files.

Imaging a corrupt filesystem is of course going to move the corruption with it.

I would start off by testing the server's RAM, raid controller and disks to make sure they aren't causing corruption.  Then wipe the drives and start over.  If you weren't doing backups yet that basically means the work so far setting it up had no value to you.  So start over and do it right.  And start backing it up right away.

Comment: I fear that is what we will need to do.  The client that I am working with procrastinated and did not provide a backup drive until they were live for 2 months, so we have production data that may cause a problem in this.  Was hoping to be able to fix the current system.